# 2D array - Detect if a position is inside a closed pattern

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have the following:

```
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,X,X,X,0,
  0,0,0,X,X,X,X,0,X,0,
  0,0,0,X,0,A,0,0,X,0,
  0,0,0,X,0,0,X,X,X,0,
  0,0,0,X,X,X,X,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 }
```

As you can see, it's clearly that A is inside surrounded by all the X's ( Diagonal not counting ). So can I detect if a point in the array is surrounded by X's and it's of course closed? Any rescursive algorithm? I thought about the following pseudocode:

```
bool IsSurroundedByX( Vector2 A )
{
     if A is an extrem from the matrix ( column is 0 or N-1 || row is 0 or M -1 ) and not an X return false
     if A is an X return true
     return IsSurroundedByX( A + left ) && 
            IsSurroundedByX( A + right ) && 
            IsSurroundedByX( A + bottom ) && 
            IsSurroundedByX( A + top ) && 
}
```

But I think it's not going to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there.

Your approach is basically a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)  (which is a variation if [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)), which would work, but you are missing one small thing - make sure your recursion stop.

As it currently stands, you'll have infinite loops because you allow `left-right-left-right-left-right-....` and such patterns.

This issue can be handled easily by adding `visited` set. This set is basically a set of all nodes, and if your recursion comes to a node that you have already visited - it doesn't do anything. This will allow you to traverse all cells at most once (and avoid the infinite loop).

Comment: So if A is a visited node just return false?

Comment: @marcg11 No, return true.